# How to Remove the Pivot Header but Keep Functionality

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In a previous question [How to Change Pivot Header Template in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902064/how-to-change-pivot-header-template-in-windows-phone-8) I retemplated the Pivot Header, but I was wondering how it would be possible to remove the headers all together, while maintaining the functionality of a PivotControl.

Comment: You can set it blank as a quick workaround like shown here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139001/windows-phone-8-remove-pivot-header

Comment: How are users suppose to know there are other "tabs/pages" without the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that I use for the same purpose, it works fine:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="PivotStyle1" TargetType="phone:Pivot">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:Pivot">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <primitives:PivotHeadersControl x:Name="HeadersListElement" />
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="PivotItemStyle1" TargetType="phone:PivotItem">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<phone:Pivot x:Name="MyPivot"
    Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle1}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource PivotItemStyle1}">
    <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate><!-- dummy content to show that no header is on the screen -->
            <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid Background="Red" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    <!-- we need empty header template to hide the pivotitem title completely -->
    <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate />
    </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
</phone:Pivot>
```