# Windows phone WinRT Pivot remove header and title space

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I want to remove the space the title and headers normaly occupy inside a Pivot when using Winrt toolkit with Windows phone 8.1 so the content of the Pivotitem is filling the screen.

here is what i tried:

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <Thickness x:Key="PivotPortraitThemePadding">19,0,0,0</Thickness>
    <Thickness x:Key="PivotLandscapeThemePadding">19,25,0,0</Thickness>
    <Style x:Key="CustomPivotStyle" TargetType="Pivot">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Pivot">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Orientation">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TitleContentControl">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotPortraitThemePadding}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TitleContentControl">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotLandscapeThemePadding}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="TitleContentControl" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Style="{StaticResource PivotTitleContentControlStyle}"/>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}" VerticalSnapPointsType="None" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                            <PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header" Background="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                    <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderTranslateTransform" TranslateX="0"/>
                                    </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                </PivotHeaderPanel>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter">
                                    <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform" X="0"/>
                                    </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                </ItemsPresenter>
                            </PivotPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>



<Pivot Style="{StaticResource CustomPivotStyle}">
    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate/>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <Pivot.TitleTemplate>
        <DataTemplate/>
    </Pivot.TitleTemplate>
    <PivotItem>
        <TextBlock Text="text1" FontSize="100"/>
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem>
        <TextBlock Text="text2" FontSize="100"/>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

that didnt work. Is there an alternative way off doing it or am I just doing it wrong?
**Just setting the top margin to a negative value is not an option for me**

Comment: You will have to play with [the *Style* of your *Pivot*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25327517/2681948).

Comment: @Romasz thanks I have seen and read that post I allready changed the style by setting the top padding in PivotPortraitThemePadding to 0 it did help a little but there is still a gap

Comment: Then you should edit your question and put there more information (especially code) - what you have already done.

Comment: if you are using wp 8.1 winrt maybe a flipview would be a good choice?

Comment: Try this style for Pivot to hide headers - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28767442/1219241

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[edit]: The tip fex gave me seems to also work using a flipview is possible too!

```
<FlipView>
    <FlipViewItem>
        <TextBlock Text="text1" FontSize="100"/>
    </FlipViewItem>
    <FlipViewItem>
        <TextBlock Text="text2" FontSize="100"/>
    </FlipViewItem>
</FlipView>
```

solved it with [the link Romasz provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327517/windows-phone-8-1-pivot-custom-header-style) i set PivotPortraitThemePadding to 0 and then manipulated the margin of the item inside the pivotitem to make it sit flush with the top.

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <Thickness x:Key="PivotPortraitThemePadding">19,0,0,0</Thickness>
    <Thickness x:Key="PivotLandscapeThemePadding">19,25,0,0</Thickness>
    <Style x:Key="CustomPivotStyle" TargetType="Pivot">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Pivot">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Orientation">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TitleContentControl">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotPortraitThemePadding}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="TitleContentControl">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotLandscapeThemePadding}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="TitleContentControl" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" Style="{StaticResource PivotTitleContentControlStyle}"/>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}" VerticalSnapPointsType="None" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ZoomMode="Disabled">
                            <PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header" Background="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                    <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderTranslateTransform" TranslateX="0"/>
                                    </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                </PivotHeaderPanel>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter">
                                    <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform" X="0"/>
                                    </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                </ItemsPresenter>
                            </PivotPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Pivot Style="{StaticResource CustomPivotStyle}">

    <PivotItem>
        <TextBlock Text="text1" FontSize="100" Foreground="White" Margin="0,-20,0,0"/>
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <TextBlock Text="text2" FontSize="100" Margin="0,-20,0,0"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

Comment: Look out, because the margin you have set results from the font itself. Check it by putting `<Rectangle Width="300" Height="40" Margin="0" Fill="Blue" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>` instead of *TextBlock* - with this margin some letter may be cut off.